# How can I write a HUSH shell script that tests the result of each command?

Tags: shell, scripting

How can I make this script review that status of commands and exit if any of the fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo JFFS2 Preparation

cd /root

/root/config 1 > /root/formatted

if grep "PAR_JFFS2_FORMATTED = -1" /root/formatted; then
  echo Need to Format MTD2
  rm -f /root/formatted

  flash_eraseall -j /dev/mtd2

  echo Marking file system as formatted
  /root/config 1 1355270400

  mount -t jffs2 -o noatime /dev/mtdblock2 /mnt

  echo "Formmatted" > /mnt/formatted.txt

else
  mount -t jffs2 -o noatime /dev/mtdblock2 /mnt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `set -e` early in the script, or change the `#!` line to `#!/bin/sh -e`, which will have the same effect.

This sets the `errexit` shell option, which means that the script will exit as soon as a command is returning a non-zero exit status, with the following exceptions (taken from [the POSIX description of `set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)):

1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command
                pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure
                of the pipeline itself shall be considered.
2. The `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound
                list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, or `elif` reserved word, a
                pipeline beginning with the `!`  reserved word, or any command
                of an AND-OR list other than the last.
3. If the exit status of a compound command other than a
                subshell command was the result of a failure while `-e` was
                being ignored, then `-e` shall not apply to this command.

An alternative is to add `|| exit` after each command that you'd like to exit after, if they fail.  For example

```
flash_eraseall -j /dev/mtd2 || exit
```

Comment: This answer might have worked on another shell, but the HUSH shell is very minimal. Here is the error I was given while trying to use the "-e" setting:
`/bin/sh: invalid option -- e
BusyBox v1.17.4 (2017-02-13 16:44:23 EST) multi-call binary.

No help available.`

Comment: @WayneTaylor I think you need to say what hush shell you're using. Busybox's `sh` understands the `-e` option and `set -e`.

Comment: Dear Kusalanand, I specified BusyBox v1.17.4 and hush. There are several shells to choose from including Ash. But hush (2008-07-14), as shown did not support -e.

Answer (score 0):

After each command in bash the return code is stored in `$?` variable. If the command is successful its value should be

```
successfulcommand    
echo $?
0
```

In case o error the result is non zero and varies depending on the error.

```
unsuccessfulcommand
echo $?
2
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the HUSH shell testing the results of $$. I tried:
if (($? != 0)); then
  echo "Can't execute ....error($?)"
  exit -2
fi


But the code always seems to run and even prints error(0).